# Git: fetch pull requests from GitHub

Tags: git, github

As far as I understand, GitHub/Lab uses [Git custom references / internals](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-References) to store Pull Requests in repository.

How can I fetch all the pull requests in my cloned repository?

Comment: `git ls-remote origin | grep -F refs/pull/`

Comment: @phd that's exactly what I need! Please move it to answer section and I'll accept.

Answer from VonC is also great but it is a bit overkill for my particular problem :)

Comment: @DmitryPetrov phd's comment would not fetch anything, only list GitHub remote PR branches (not GitLab or BitBucket)

Comment: @VonC you are right. Is it possible to fetch it in a single command with no changing configs?

Comment: @DmitryPetrov `gh pr list` is nice too (as mentioned in the answer). No config change needed.

Comment: yes, but I'm looking for vanilla Git approach that should work with any other Git hostings

Comment: @DmitryPetrov Which is why my answer points out the different namespaces used by different Git repository hosting services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check which namespace is used for those requests:

- GitHub: `refs/pull/`
- GitLab: `refs/merge-requests/`
- BitBucket: `refs/pull-requests/`

Then, as illustrated [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/karlhorky/88b3c8c258796cd3eb97615da36e07be), you can configure your remote [refspecs](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec):

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = git@github.com:joyent/node.git
    fetch = +refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*
```

---

Also, for GitHub, you can also use [`gh pr list`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_list) and [`gh pr checkout`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_checkout) to list/filter your PRs, and checkout only the ones you need.